# creating custom conda channel from local pkgs directory

Tags: anaconda, conda

Conda seems to keep a cache of it's local packages `<conda_root>/pkgs`.

If I create a custom channel from these packages (the .tar or .conda files) using `conda index <channel_path>` and then try and install the same files from this channel with: `conda install <pkg> -c file:///<path_to_channel> --override-channels` I get all sorts of version resolution errors.

Is there a better, more robust way to capture locally installed packages to a custom channel?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Steve yeah, it turned out this approach is flawed as the packages are not in the correct platform folder e.g. noarch/linux-64 etc so what I ended up doing was unzip the files and reading the meta.json to find out what platform they are for then copying the tar to the relevant folder in a separate directory (doing all the unziping in memory in Python, naturally)

Comment: That sounds like a useful script. May I ask, could you share the script on GitHub?

Comment: I agree with Steve and would be grateful to see that script in a dedicated answer to this question as well.